# Why enter operator new in crt\src\newop.cpp with /MD option

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msvcrt

I'm working on a large project and it's built on msvc 7.1.

In order to track memory problems I've hooked the malloc, free, and operator new/delete
family functions in different versions of crt-runtime dll libraries(like msvcp71.dll, msvcp100.dll, msvcrt.dll, ect).

I found that the STL allocator of containers(std::string and std::vector)
will enter an operator new function which lives in "(vspath)...crt\src\newop.cpp",
rather than the exported dll function of operator new.

Why does this happen?
The "runtime library" option of the project was set to "Multi-Thread DLL(/MD)".

Comment: Any class can override new/delete.

Comment: You mean newop.cpp was just a STL overriding operator new ?

Comment: That's very possible - however, it will almost certainly end up in a `malloc` at some point.

Comment: `crt\src\newop.cpp` is the SOURCE of the crt; your DLL linked in `newop.obj`. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: for general using, it's not a problem. for tracking, it's a block, and it does nothing at all.